# Использование NodeJS для отрисовки текста на фото

Tags: node.js, node-modules, photo

**Я начал изучать NodeJS и задался вопросом: существует ли здесь какая-либо библиотека для отрисовки текста на фото?**

Поясняю. Допустим, у меня есть игровой бот в одной из популярных социальных сетей и я хочу посредством использования NodeJS визуализировать профиль: в live-time создавать картинку с данными пользователя.

Пример:
[image: Пример отрисовки текста на фото]

**Кто-нибудь знает такую библиотеку?**

Comment: визуализация происходит на клиенте, а на сервере... Какое `nodejs` имеет отношение к фото...???

Comment: @Air, похоже имеется ввиду [Air flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/8524023.png)

Comment: а это точно должно быть растровое изображение? точно ли что оно обязано генерироваться без участия браузера?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp

Comment: @Yaant, не то, глядя на [package/jimp#methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#methods) - [поворот, обрезка, ресайз, ... и т.п.]

Comment: @qwabra а `image.print()` оттуда же чем не то?

Comment: "оттуда же" это если бы он был в "методах", а так, да - не заметил https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#writing-text

Answer (score 0):

первая же ссылка из гугла, либа **мной не проверена**:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric

  > Dependencies (2)
  >   [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas), [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)

  - (habr) [Знакомимся с Fabric.js. Часть 1-я](https://habr.com/ru/post/162367)
    как я понимаю, от создателей

**выглядит как** реализация браузерного **канваса для ноды**.
если это так - все либы и обучалки для канваса подойдут и для этой библиотеки.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API